# D3JS - Optimize tween transform on thousands elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geometry

I work on a satellite project using D3.js, and I try to represent them as a circle undulating according to their properties. To animate them, I use a tween on the `transform` property. You can see an example here with one satellite : https://jsfiddle.net/b7kL980y/.

But I need to render much more elements. With 55 elements, the animation is still fluid : https://jsfiddle.net/sw9vbzgy/1/. But when I try with ~1500 elements, the circles don't even render (https://jsfiddle.net/wgpr2ba1/1/). I also tried to use `cy` and `cx` interpolation instead of `transform` but it doesn't work neither.

Do you have some recommandations or ideas ?

```
var svg = d3.select('#canvas').append('svg')
    .attr('width', window.innerWidth)
    .attr('height', window.innerHeight);

var center = {
    x: window.innerWidth / 2,
    y: window.innerHeight / 2
};

d3.json('https://api.myjson.com/bins/futij', function(error, json) {
    if(error) console.error(error);

    var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([-100, 62000])
        .range([0, window.innerHeight]);

    var scaleSize = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1, 8000])
        .range([3, 30]);

    var scaleCosinus = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([0, Math.PI * 2]);

    var colors = {
        'Government': 'rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.6)',
        'Commercial': 'rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6)',
        'Military': 'rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.6)',
        'Civil': 'rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.6)',
        'Military/Government': 'rgba(241, 196, 15, 0.6)',
        'Government/Commercial': 'rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.6)',
        'Military/Commercial': 'rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.6)',
        'Government/Civil': 'rgba(149, 165, 166, 0.6)',
    };

    var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(json)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
            var size = d.launch_mass != "" && d.launch_mass != undefined ? scaleSize(d.launch_mass) : 3;
            return -1 * scaleSize(size) - 1;
        })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return scaleY(d.perigee) })
        .attr('r', function(d) { return d.launch_mass != "" && d.launch_mass != undefined ? scaleSize(d.launch_mass) : 3 })
        .style('fill', function(d) { return colors[d.users] });

    circles.transition()
        .each(animate);

    function animate(d) {
        var circle = d3.select(this);
        circle.attr('cx', parseFloat(circle.attr('r') + 1) * - 1)
            .attr('cy', scaleY(d.perigee))
            .transition()
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .duration(d.period * 20)
            .attrTween('transform', function(d) {
               return function(t) {
                   return "translate(" + t * (window.innerWidth + parseFloat(circle.attr('r')) + 1) + ", " + scaleY(Math.cos(scaleCosinus(t)) * -1  * ((d.apogee - d.perigee) / 2) + d.perigee * 2) + ")";
               }
            })
            .on('end', animate);
    }
});
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Sounds like canvas would be a more appropriate technology here than SVG. Although even with that your UX is probably broken, 1500 simultaneously moving objects rarely makes sense.

Comment: Do you have a case where it still runs but is laggy? The 1500 element link does not even render so I can't see what's wrong. Generally you want to use Chrome dev tool's Performance tab to profile your app and figure out which step is taking up most resources and whether it is CPU or memory that is the bottleneck.

Comment: The limit is near 440 (1 or 2 more and the browser can't render). Here's a link : https://jsfiddle.net/y0zkydmc/1/. The main activity under Chrome dev tools is "Recalculating style", which is normal (I guess).

Comment: I use canvas instead of SVG and it works great. Thanks @RobertLongson for the tip